# Minimal polynomial of all elements in a finite field extension of $\mathbb{F}_3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $i \in \mathbb{F}_3$ be a zero of $x^2+ 1$. Let $\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{F}_3(i)$, and determine the minimal polynomial of $\alpha\in \mathbb{F}$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$.

I'm trying to solve the question above. I showed that $\mathbb{F}$ is a field extension with 9 elements. Thus $\mathbb{F}\cong \mathbb{F}_9$.
It's clear that we shouldn't bother about the elements contained in $\mathbb{F}_3$, nor $\pm i$, since they're trivial for the former and we already know them for the latter. But there are 4 more elements to go. I don't know how they look like, so it's hard for me to imagine how I could even get their respective minimal polynomials.

I would really appreciate any help possible.

Comment: The field only has $9$ elements, as you remark.  You should be able to write all of them out explicitly in terms of the elements of $\mathbb F_3$ and $i$.  You will have terms like $1+i$ and $-1+i$ for example.

Comment: Can you please explain why I can write them out in terms of elements of $\mathbb{F_3}$ and $i$?

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you know what $\mathbb F_3(i)$ means?

Comment: That was probably bad phrasing of my question, my apologies. Instead of 'why' that is, I meant how could I write the other four elements. It's not really clear to me how exactly I could write them out, since I would suppose you could just take any arbitrary linear combination.

Comment: I don't think you understand.  The elements of $\mathbb F_3(i)$ are precisely those elements of the form $A+Bi$ where $A,B\in \{0,1,-1\}$.  There are $9$ such, clearly.  Here I am writing the elements of $\mathbb F_3$ as $\{0, 1, -1\}$ though of course you could use $\{0,1,2\}$ if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

As lulu mentioned, the elements of $\mathbb{F}_{3}(i)$ are precisely those of the form $a + bi$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{F}_{3}$

Consider $\alpha = a + bi \in \mathbb{F}_{3}(i)$. Now let $x = a + bi$, where $a, b \in \mathbb{F}_{3}$. Then

$$x - a = bi \iff (x-a)^{2} = -b^{2} \iff x^{2} - 2ax + a^{2} + b^{2} = 0.$$

Hence $h = x^{2} - 2ax + a^{2} + b^{2} \in \mathbb{F}_{3}[x]$ is possibly the desired minimal polynomial. We have that $\alpha$ is a root of $h$, the other root of $h$ is its conjugate $\overline{\alpha} = a - bi$. Now either $b = 0$ or $b \neq 0$.

If $b = 0$: we have that $\alpha = a \in \mathbb{F}_{3}$, and the linear (thus irreducible) polynomial $X - a \in \mathbb{F}_{3}[x]$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{F}_{3}$

If $b \neq 0$: we have that $\alpha = a + bi \in \mathbb{F}_{3}(i)$. Note that $h$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{3}$ since $i \notin \mathbb{F}_{3}$. Then $h$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $\mathbb{F}_{3}$